# RxSwift interval (Timer) in background

Tags: swift, background, scheduler, intervals

I have one Observable that each second increments by one and this makes that one label gets updated.

Is it wrong to execute the observable in the background queue? When I modify the UI I’m doing it in the Main Thread.

As the Observable is in the background thread can create a delay?

Here is my code:

```
    Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.updateCountdown()
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I believe as long as you're observing it on the MainScheduler there won't be any problem.
It is perfectly fine to do some work on the background thread and then update the UI on the main thread afterward.